# Self - Referencing in MYSQL causing: ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, blockchain

I am creating a **Blockchain** for a school project, and I have to use MySQL, but I am getting some errors when I try to add a foreign key that refers to the same table, what should I do to fix it?

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Blockchain;
use Blockchain;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(
    Public_Key CHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY,
    Hashed_Private_Key CHAR(64) UNIQUE KEY NOT NULL,
    Balance FLOAT,
    Transactions_Done INT,
    Rewards_Won INT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Blocks(
    Block_ID CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    Previous_Block_Hash CHAR(64),
    Transactions JSON,
    Nonce VARCHAR(64),
    Block_Hash CHAR(64),
    Submitter_ID CHAR(64)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Unmined_Transactions(
    Transaction_ID CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    Sender_ID CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Reciever_ID CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Amount FLOAT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Mined_Transactions(
    Transaction_ID CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    Sender_ID CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Reciever_ID CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Amount FLOAT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS All_Transactions(
    Transaction_ID CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    Sender_ID CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Reciever_ID CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Amount FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Mined BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Unmined_Transactions ADD FOREIGN KEY (Sender_ID) REFERENCES Users(Public_Key);
ALTER TABLE Unmined_Transactions ADD FOREIGN KEY (Reciever_ID) REFERENCES Users(Public_Key);

ALTER TABLE Mined_Transactions ADD FOREIGN KEY (Sender_ID) REFERENCES Users(Public_Key);
ALTER TABLE Mined_Transactions ADD FOREIGN KEY (Reciever_ID) REFERENCES Users(Public_Key);

ALTER TABLE All_Transactions ADD FOREIGN KEY (Sender_ID) REFERENCES Users(Public_Key);
ALTER TABLE All_Transactions ADD FOREIGN KEY (Reciever_ID) REFERENCES Users(Public_Key);


ALTER TABLE Blocks ADD FOREIGN KEY (Previous_Block_Hash) REFERENCES Blocks(Block_Hash);
ALTER TABLE Blocks ADD FOREIGN KEY (Submitter_ID) REFERENCES Users(Public_Key);
```

The 2nd last Alter Statement is causing the error, i.e.
ALTER TABLE Blocks ADD FOREIGN KEY (Previous_Block_Hash) REFERENCES Blocks(Block_Hash);

Running this line is as follows:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSWxx.png)
All other statements work well

Comment: You can’t have a foreign key in a column without an index. Create indexes before! The error is self explanatory. Next time kindly don’t post errors on images, paste errors as text.

Answer (score 2):

I got the Answer, I just needed to change the structure of the table, to make Block_Hash as a Unique Key, since you cannot reference a Non-Unique/Non-Primary Key:
Here is the changed Table Structure of Blocks Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Blocks(
    Block_ID CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    Previous_Block_Hash CHAR(64) UNIQUE KEY,
    Transactions JSON,
    Nonce VARCHAR(64),
    Block_Hash CHAR(64) UNIQUE KEY NOT NULL,
    Submitter_ID CHAR(64) NOT NULL
);
```